# webclient doesn't download the web page completely

Tags: c#, webclient

Have code for download page:

```
 System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
 client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/20.0.1");
 byte[] feedBytes;
 string url;
 url = @"http://www.marathonbet.co.uk/en/betting/Football";
 string fullPage = string.Empty;
 try
 {
      feedBytes = client.DownloadData(url);
 }
 catch (System.Net.WebException)
 {
      return;
 }
string fullPage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(feedBytes);
```

As result 'fullpage' contains only part of page. In the browser loading of the page happens gradually. How to download full page?

Comment: Why are you ignoring exceptions? Remove that try/catch block and see what happens. At the least, capture the exception and display `ex.ToString()` so you know what's wrong.

Comment: Your code works for me. I get the full page in the `fullPage` after executing your code...

Comment: nemsv - I think you had receive about 300 Kb of info, full page is more than 2 Mb

Comment: Add to catch 'Console.WriteLine("WebException");'. Result not changed.

Comment: Very likely the problem is that the page uses JavaScript to generate content, and `WebClient.DownloadData` doesn't execute JavaScript; it just downloads that one page.

Comment: Are exist method or class for working with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static string GetHTMLDocument(string url)
        {
            var result = "";
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                result = wc.DownloadString(url);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: FYI, you can use `return wc.DownloadString(url);`

Comment: no difference - result contains only small part(about 3-5%) of page

Comment: That means, that there's probably dynamic content that's loading after the document loads.  Not much you can do about that.

Comment: Not exist way to download dynamic content?

Comment: You don't *download* dynamic content.  You execute the script that generates the dynamic content.